# creating a grouping ID based on values in another column

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to figure out how to do this in Oracle PL/SQL.

I want to create values in a column that would group records based on when a certain value appears in another column.  For example, based on the values in the first column in this image, I want to create the values in the 'Group' column.  The value of 'red' is always the first value in a group of records.  Any subsequent color value other than 'red' belongs to the same group.  The next 'red' value means a new 'group' value needs to be created.

[image: [1]]

Any ideas on how to create the values in the 'Group' column?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: please dont supply your data in pictures bu as text formatted as code

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, let me assume that you have a column that specifies the ordering.  I'll just call it `id`.

Your `grp` column is simply the sum of the reds up to and including any row.  This is easy:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when colors = 'red' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as grp
from t;
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using recnum in sql loader to maintain the desired record order. 
 This solution works as well.  Thanks for your help with this Gordon L.!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ROWS BETWEEN Clause to get the sum of "red" color till the current ROW

```
          SELECT a.color,
             SUM(DECODE(color,'red',1,0) ) OVER ( ORDER BY ROWNUM 
                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) rn
           FROM colors a;
```

Comment: I tried this first thing today, the results are exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks Kaushik N.!